# Old Brown "sour belgian"

Tags: yeast, bottling, conditioning

I have an Belgian sour that has been in it's secondary for 18 months. With a terminal gravity of 1010 for over the last year, what is the best way to bottle condition this beer? New yeast? Blend?

Comment: the real question is what's the best way for me to get a bottle?  Belgians homebrews make me drool, but I've not found any aged beyond a few months (having a hard time not sipping away at my Tripel until it's at 6mos this summer)

Answer (score 4):

If by bottle condition you mean to carbonate, I'd add some fresh yeast.  Preferably a neutral ale yeast strain like WLP001.  I'd recommend using just a 1/3rd to 1/2 a vial of WLP001.  Add it to your bottling bucket along with your priming sugar prior to racking over from fermentor to bucket.  This should ensure more than enough healthy yeast at bottling.

Answer (score 1):

T-58 is a dry yeast that is supposedly the same strain as WLP500 and is designed for bottling big/old Belgians. Sprinkle in a packet of that stuff into your carboy the day before bottling and you should be good to go.